# How to define this RewriteRule in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite the following url into another one.

domain.com/abc    to     domain.com/news.php?name=123

I defined the following rule in my .htacesss file.

RewriteRule abc /news.php?name=123 [PT]

**It works but I only want "domain.com/abc" rewrite to  /news.php?name=123
What I have now will match any words which contains "abc" and rewrite to destination.**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^abc$ news.php?name=123
```

Hopefully this should work. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: The ^ sign defines the start of the URL and the $ sign signifies the end of the string to be matched.

to be more specific to your domain, use

RewriteRule ^domain\.com/abc$ news.php?name=123

Comment: [This](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html) website helped me a lot when I was first writing these rules. Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^abc news.php?name=123
```